# How to make 20 bit address by using two 16 bit registers?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, real-mode, memory-segmentation

IAPX88 can deal with 1 mega byte memory(20 bit addressing), now my question is how we make a 20 bit address by using two 16 bit registers.please give an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IAPX88 physical addresses are computed by taking the segment register, shifting it to the left 4 bits, and adding the offset register.

For example, the physical address in memory that code executes is  `(CS<<4)+IP` where CS is the Code Segment and IP is the Instruction Pointer.

You can get details on the [Intel 8086 wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8086).

Answer (score 1):

We can do this using shifted addition. we deal with  2-addresses: the logical address which is represented as two 16-bit addresses and the physical address which is the actual 20-bit address.

Remember that, since we are dealing with hexadecimals, each number represents 4 bits.

e.g. we want to represent the address: `7 2 3 A 5` using two 16-bit addresses, we can do using the two addresses: `7 2 3 A` and `0 0 0 5`.

First, we shift the first address by four bits to the left: `7 2 3 A 0` which is called the **base**.

Then, we add the the second address: `0 0 0 5` which is called the **offset**.

The result of this operation is a new 20-bit address: `7 2 3 A 5`.

If our base is the the `CS` which is the start of the code segment and our offset is the instruction pointer `IP`, we can describe the previous operation as follows: `(CS << 4) + IP`

Note: we can describe any 20-bit physical address using many 16:16-bit logical addresses, but each 2-logical addresses will have only one physical address.
[image]